# Mi web no se ve desde el margen superior

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, formularios, plugin

Al ingresar a la web http://sandwich-express.com/ la home se visualiza automáticamente desde el input form de plug in wordpress para completar el campo y no quiero que esto pase. No encuetro la forma de eliminar esto ya que nunca me pasó. Quiero que la web se vea normalmente desde la parte superior evitando el scroll.
Si entran a la web se van a dar cuenta de lo que les digo.

Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Mauricio. Por favor evita publicar enlaces externos donde se encuentre o se explique el problema, intenta que la pregunta contenga todo lo necesario para entender el problema y analizarlo. Te recomiendo revisar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Con esto en mente, podrás editar la pregunta para que pueda ser respondida por miembros de la comunidad.

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda que indicases qué plugin estás usando (y puede que también su versión). Las preguntas deberían contener toda la información necesaria para responer sin necesidad de visitar un sitio externo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifica la configuración de tu plugin, este tiene una configuración *"On page load move the mouse cursor to the search field?"*  seguramente tienes habilitada dicha opción.

Te adjunto la documentación donde se explica esta configuración, en la sección de *"user experience"*

https://wpstorelocator.co/document/configure-wp-store-locator/

Comment: Gracias Roger! tenia la solución frente a mis ojos y no la ví. Gracias otra vez!